# Serializing reference of stateful + stateless objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, factory

This is kind of a design problem:

```
class Suite
{
  List<Plugins> Plugins {get;set;} 
}

class DataCollector : Plugin
{
  string Property1 {get;set;}
  string Property2 {get;set;}

  public void PrintMyName();    
}

class Measurement: Plugin
{
  string Property1 {get;set;}
  string Property2 {get;set;}

  public void PrintMyName();    
}
```

Now, I want the class suite to be serializable. The problem here is this:

1. XMl serialization is basically used to serialize DTO kind of objects so you basically serialize/deserialize your stateful properties and that is fine
2. This particular class which is going to serialized contains of Type Plugin(which contains combination of properties which contains some property values) + functionalists.
3. Which means I need to use factory to get the real instance of the object for Plugin to come to life with all its functionality with the property values.

Am I looking at an XMLSrializable + Factory combination? Is there any good elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: What's a "functionalist"?  Also, probably best not to type your code in MS Word where keywords that should not be capitalized are unfortunately capitalized.  (`class`, `public`, `void`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not implement the `IDeserializationCallback` interface so upon deserialization you can bring your object back to life via a call to your factory.

I don't really understand the purpose of your classes, but I will give an example as best I can:

```
public class MyDataClass : IDeserializationCallback
{

   public int SimpleKeyProperty { get; set; }
   public string TextProperty{ get; set; }

   public void OnDeserialization(object sender)
   {
      //upon deserialization use the int key to get the latest value from
      //factory (this is make believe...)
      TextProperty = SomeFactory.GetCurrentValue( this.SimpleKeyProperty) ;
   }
}
```

Comment: i was thinking of saperating the class into two parts DTO + service. which means DTO will be dumped into XML and the service will be brough to life by factory. But need a way to bind them with each other

Comment: I think implementing this interface will allow you to do that.

Comment: Can you scribble out a blueprint signature of this Interface?